# How to get 10 days from today data using queries

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Hi I am using below query for getting 10 days data using query. but i am confused for this query could you please give me suggestion to achieve this requirement.

```
select we.StartDateTime,v.EmailAddress from DE1_webActivity_19FEB as we  
where  DATEDIFF(day, we.StartDateTime, GETDATE())<10 and 
                 v.EmailAddress!=''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the last 10 days of data your WHERE clause syntax just needs a bit of work:

```
WHERE [VisitStartDateTime] >= DATEADD(DAY, -10, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
AND [VisitStartDateTime] < DATEADD(DAY, -11, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

Comment: Hi  @TCassa 
  I used above query where condition but iam getting extra date data . i want only 10 days data with include today date . how to achieve this condition .
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I always second-guess myself with datediff and dateadd.  I normally do something like this instead:

```
select 
we.visitStartDateTime
, v.EmailAddress 
from DE1_webActivity_19FEB as we  
where  
we.visitStartDateTime >= convert(date, getDate()-10)
and isnull(v.EmailAddress,'') != ''
```

This selects all records with a `visitStartDate` on or after 10 days ago -- for anyone that has an `emailAddress`.

You can subtract days without a function -- `getDate()-10`

The convert to `date` just sets the time portion to midnight -- `00:00`

I'm also assuming you're trying to select `visitStartDateTime` and not `StartDateTime`.

Comment: Yes your right i am not modified before just  now i modified.
Thank you